# All of a sudden. Can't build my project(Game) & sync with Gradle (Libgdx)

Tags: java, android, libgdx

So, i've been developing several Games for Android.

And im currently working on an update for my latest game.

I shut down my computer normally yesterday, no problems & no errors...

... Today when i logged into Windows & opened my project in Android studio i get this strabge error:

**Gradle 'projectname' project refresh failed
   Error:Cause: org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils**

I don't know whats causing this error...

I can open my old project(game created with libgdx) and it works just fine.

But when i open my recent one it wont compile & gradle wont sync.

Even if i create a new project it will give me the same error.

Google Doesn't say anything about this :(....

**what i've done to try fixing:**

- Reinstalled Android Studio
- Removed all Java Version. JDK + JDE.
- Updated All SDK, Raspitory, Google Play services, etc..

As my old project was created exactly in the same way & works, i find this very frustrating. The only things that is different from my new project is that my old game is created in an older version of Libgdx, older Version of Android Studio etc...

What's strange is that it all worked just fine yesterday!

Anyone?

i'm desperate. Put so much time into this project!

Comment: Screenshot of error: http://www.crazycubes.net/help.png

Comment: So im currently setting up the envirement on my laptop to see if problem is there appell..

Comment: Clean project maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing downloaded gradle dependencies for org.apache.commons.io from your system and rebuild the project. The downloaded dependencies can be found in .m2 folder (In linux it will be a hidden folder in home directory)

Comment: Ok thanks for help! i forgot to mention that i also had cleared all cache files & folders, deleted gradle etc. 

I got it to work after like 8 hours. What i did:

• Removed **everything**. Android Studio, Java, Cache files, Gradle, Old sdks. Everything. 

After many hours of reinstalling & updating it now works...